# Run time control

Tags: c#, .net

My program adds a new control (a panel with richbox, textbox) for each new item, and I want to save these controls with its data without using text file or xml file. I read about serilization and I am already using it for saving my tree view by this code:

```
if(File.Exists(filename))
    using (Stream file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open ))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(file, TRV.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());
        file.Close();
    }
```

I ask if there is a way to save my newly added control by this way?

Comment: Why don't you want to use text or XML files? Most serializers have the disadvantage that they write specific version information to the file that might not be necessary. If you want to change the class later (e.g. make the TextBox a RichTextBox or just upgrade to the next version), you can't use the old files anymore. Therefore, it is more reasonable to save as little information as possible in a file. And a text or XML file seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: I think serialization is more easy and fast  than saving properties or information in XML file or text file , but if serialization prevent me to upgrade my class , it will be not a  better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize your objects this way:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClassType));
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\SerializedData.xml");
writer.Serialize(file, youClass);
file.Close();
```

Comment: but this method does not work on control serialization "there is an error "There was an error reflecting type 'extemp.AddPanel'.""

Comment: according to 2 days searching there is no binary or xml serialization for   all controls , except a few like tree view :(